# Finding to which interval does the data fit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am writing a code to find how much time does it need to pass since the last bid depending on users' karma points. At the moment the code goes through all the possible solutions and its O(n). I am thinking of optimizing this somehow to O(logn), but I don't know how to achieve it.

```
function isBidValid(userKarma: number, minKarma: number, maxKarma: number, timePassed: number, timeToPass: number, message: string) {
  if (userKarma > minKarma && userKarma < maxKarma && timePassed < timeToPass) {
    throw errors.create('NotAvailable', {
      userKarma, timePassed, timeToPass, message,
    });
  }
}

const usersLastBid = await Bid.findOne({ item: itemId, user: userId }).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1);
const timePassed = ((currentTime - usersLastBid?._id.getTimestamp().getTime()) / 1000 / 60);

if (usersLastBid) {
  isBidValid(user.karma, -14, -6, 0, 1, 'Can not make 2 bids');
  isBidValid(user.karma, -5, 5, timePassed, 90, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 6, 15, timePassed, 45, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 16, 29, timePassed, 30, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 30, 39, timePassed, 20, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 40, 54, timePassed, 15, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 55, 64, timePassed, 12, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 65, 74, timePassed, 10, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 75, 84, timePassed, 8, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 85, 99, timePassed, 7, 'Not enough time has passed');
  isBidValid(user.karma, 99, 101, timePassed, 5, 'Not enough time has passed');
}
```

Comment: Ten function calls aren't really worth optimizing, but you can use binary search to find the interval in logarithmic time.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `try/catch` around each call?